# How to get a “BILL” from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

simple restaurant schema

[image: schema]

postgresql with insertion and an order transaction
https://hastebin.com/cobuquzobo.sql

each guest/s at a `sitting_table` is a new table

each order on the same `sitting_table` will be a new `orderr`

bill would be taken by entering `sitting_table_id`, `orderr` `id`s that are with the entered `sitting_table_id`, up to `orderr_menu_item`...

(using psycopg2/python, printing in linux cmd)

I want for example to print a BILL, and I'd like to have them stored...

now here I am kind of lost and don't really know what to do or should do

bill data would be like:

```
bill nr23
order2
  cola × 2 15.50  31.00
  pizza × 2 50.00 100.00
order3
  squid × 3  50.00 150.00
total price ..
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Show your current attempt at solving this and let us know what bit is giving you problems.

Comment: this is what I have, and I don't know how to get from this to getting the data that's in code tags, and have all that stored...

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). You are not explaining what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RDBMS is not the right tool to generate a formated, customer-oriented bill. What it can do for you however, is hand you over all the information you need to generate the bill ; the rest of the job belongs to the presentation layer.

Here is a SQL query that can be used to gather the information that will allow your application to generate a bill.

It follows the relationships declared in your schema to link tables `sitting_table`, `orderr`, `orderr_menu_item`, `menu_item` and `employee`. This pretty much joins all the tables in your schema so you should be able to adapt it if additional columns are needed.

Data is aggregated by sitting table, order and menu item, with the associated quantity and computed value ; from the information you provided, it looks like this is your expected level of aggregation.

```
SELECT
    st.id sitting_table_id,
    o.id orderr_id,
    e.name employee_name,
    e.surname employee_surname,
    mi.name item_name,
    mi.cijena item_price,
    SUM(omi.quantity) item_quantity,
    SUM(omi.quantity) * mi.cijena item_value
FROM
    sitting_table st
    INNER JOIN orderr o ON o.sitting_table_id = st.id
    INNER JOIN orderr_menu_item omi ON omi.orderr_id = o.id
    INNER JOIN menu_item mi ON mi.id = omi.menu_item_id
    INNER JOIN employee e ON e.oib = o.employee_oib
-- WHERE st.id = ? AND o.orderr = ?
GROUP BY
    st.id,
    o.id,
    e.name,
    e.surname,
    omi.id,
    mi.name,
    mi.cijena
ORDER BY
    st.id,
    o.id,
    mi.name,
    mi.cijena
```

**[See the db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9w1s85XjoT99D2SkHPEhXg/1)**

You can uncomment the `WHERE` clause to restrict the selection to a given `sitting_table` and `orderr`.

Comment: If the question is unclear, comment asking for clarification, don't answer.

Comment: seems like it's not unclear to everyone, I am unsure how it's not clear to you, I gave the best explanation I could, there I have the tables, and I'd like to print a bill at the end, and possibly store it

Comment: @WASD : fair enough, I edited my answer to remove the mention to unclarity. Still, I kindly suggest you to use the query to gather the data you need, and then handle the *presentation* of that data out of the database...